# XPC error when using MLMediaLibrary from command line daemon

Tags: macos, iphoto

I'm writing a command-line daemon to read images from iPhoto.

I can init and load an `MLMediaLibrary` fine from a full-blown Cocoa application, created using the Xcode project creation tools. However, when I try and do the same from a command-line tool (also created in Xcode), the following error appears in Xcode console window:

```
MLMediaLibrary error obtaining remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application."
```

How can I access `MLMediaLibrary` from a command-line tool?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to access `MLMediaLibrary` your application has to be sandboxed and codesigned.

#### Update

It seems like you also have to add some permanent read-only access entitlements to your .entitlements file.

If you want to access Photos, iPhoto or Aperture libraries:

```
<key>com.apple.security.assets.pictures.read-only</key>
<true/>
```

If you want to access iMovie and FinalCut:

```
<key>com.apple.security.assets.movies.read-only</key>
<true/>
```

If you want to access iTunes or Logic:

```
<key>com.apple.security.assets.music.read-only</key>
<true/>
```

You can read about my poor experience with a MediaLibrary framework here:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/1125821

Comment: Thank you, this looks very helpful! I'll accept once I've had a chance to check that it works for me.

Comment: Is it possible to use MediaLibrary.framework without sandboxing my app, as I have to access some external storage devices (flash drive, etc.). See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901811/access-medialibrary-framework-without-sandboxing-on-mac

Answer (score -2):

I don't think Konstantin's statement is correct: `In order to access MLMediaLibrary your application has to be sandboxed and codesigned.`

Per my test, I can use `MediaLibrary.framework` within my application and my application is not code signed, it doesn't have an entitlements file, so it is abviously not a sandboxed app.