# Couldn't get Apple Photos details - C# macOS Sierra 10.12 Xamarin Application

Tags: c#, xamarin.mac, iphoto

I'm developing an iMac desktop application which is able to upload normal photos as well as Photos library (Previously iPhotos library) to online services like Flickr,SmugMug. Before upgrading to Sierra i was able to get details of iPhotos and could upload too but after upgradation those files/directories doesn't exist.

Below is the block by which i was getting files:

```
string PhotosLocation = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures), "Photos Library.photoslibrary/Database/apdb/Library.apdb");
```

But above is not working anymore in Sierra 10.12, if i go to finder itself to locate above mentioned path then i find 'Database' directory but no 'apdb' is there by which i can get Library.apdb

I have googled but no luck, can anybody please show me some pointers on how to get Photos Library files using C#.

Please tell me if i missed any information to share.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [Media Library Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MediaLibrary/Reference/MediaLibraryFrameworkReference/) is the place to go if your situation permit.

```
NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject> options = new NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>(
    new[] { MLMediaLibrary.MediaLoadSourceTypesKey, MLMediaLibrary.MediaLoadIncludeSourcesKey },
    new[] { new NSString(MLMediaSourceType.Image.ToString()), MLMediaSource.MediaSourcePhotosIdentifier }
);
var ml = new MLMediaLibrary(options);
ml.AddObserver("mediaSources", 0, (obj) => Console.WriteLine("Loaded"));
var src = ml.MediaSources; // returns null first time
```

In order to access `MLMediaLibrary`, your application has to be sandboxed and codesigned.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/29626032 to learn how to deal with entitlements.plist.

Comment: For this i need to change/update xamarin studio channel to Alpha from Stable? And then need to add key in entitlements file?

Comment: It does not matter whether the channel is alpha or stable. Just add key and value in entitlements.plist

Comment: This library is non-trivial to get working. I have a slightly larger example here: https://gist.github.com/chamons/9f9b6aa1f4b45ba8603cd5ba09a79b1f