# PyOBJC MLMediaLibrary

Tags: python, pyobjc

My first question goes here. Finding specific examples on PyOBJC is a challenge to say the least,
so I thought I might try just asking..
My python script:

`from MediaLibrary import *
mediaLibrary = MLMediaLibrary.alloc().initWithOptions_(None)`

Throws this error:

> [MLMediaLibraryImpl
>   connectToService]_block_invoke connection interrupted 2019-10-31
>   17:33:56.384 Python[77412:20497679] MLMediaLibrary error obtaining
>   remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097
>   "connection to service named com.apple.MediaLibraryService"
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named
>   com.apple.MediaLibraryService}

the mediaLibrary does get instantiated but is not able to fin any mediasources.

I have seen someone have problems with this in Xcode and Objective-C, saying it might be a
sandboxing or entitlements issue, but in Xcode on my Mac this runs fine without any of those.

any ideas? help?

Comment: Odd: I got the same error you did, then tried it again, and it seemed to work. It might also be helpful to alloc once, then call initWithOptions_(None) in a try block, and try it again if it fails.

Comment: OK, I see what you are saying, instantiating again removes the error but makes the object unresponsive to KeyValue-Observation. I found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372330/what-is-error-in-connection-block-invoke-2-connection-interrupted-in-ios) which talks about the `_block_invoke connection interrupted` part might be a memory limitation, but since the error is thrown before any assets are fetched or even sources found I'm still a stumped..

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a limitation on how this library can be used, the SO question "[XPC error when using MLMediaLibrary from command line daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012865/xpc-error-when-using-mlmedialibrary-from-command-line-daemon)" mentions that this framework can only be used from an app bundle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes maybe, but it's difficult to be completely confident that that is what it is. Because I too have the MediaLibrary framework running and loading all assets in a commandline tool. No entitlements or even playlist file included. I am currently trying to use this[py2app](https://www.metachris.com/2015/11/create-standalone-mac-os-x-applications-with-python-and-py2app/) tutorial to make it as much like a native App as I can but I'm not sure if there is an **OPTION** in the setup.py file I can set, or something to make it more like an app bundle?